# What is the difference?

Tags: java, multithreading, atomic

Can you explain me what is the difference between

```
i.compareAndSet(i.get(), i.get() + 1)
```

and

```
int s = i.get();
int nextS = s + 1;
i.compareAndSet(s, nextS);
```

where `i` is an `AtomicInteger`. Am I right that first way is wrong if I want to get increment value of `i`? But I can't explain why.

Comment: *"wrong"* in what way? It depends on what you want to achieve!

Comment: They're different, but that doesn't make one of them wrong and the other right. It completely depends on what end result you want. It could be the first, the second, or something else entirely.

Comment: I want to get next value of int.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first way calls `i.get()` twice. Since there's no locking here, the two calls may return different values, which is probably not what you expected.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to get next value of int

Then you probably don't want `compareAndSet` at all, you want [`updateAndGet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html#updateAndGet-java.util.function.UnaryOperator-):

```
updated = i.updateAndGet(value -> value + 1);
```

Or [`getAndUpdate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html#getAndUpdate-java.util.function.UnaryOperator-) if you want the previous value before it was updated:

```
previous = i.getAndUpdate(value -> value + 1);
```